# AngularJS - stop auto-refreshing page when state is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to stop auto-refreshing a page once a state is changed in Angular JS ?

I have the following code:

**AngularJS Controller**

```
$scope.data= [];
var findData= function() {
    service.findData().then(function (data) {
        $scope.data= data;
    });
};
findData();

$interval(function() {
    console.log("Refreshed!");
    findData();
}, 5000);
```

I have tried adding an extra condition in the $interval function:

```
$interval(function() {
    console.log("Refreshed!");
    if($state.$current.path.name == "stateWithRefresh") {
        findData();
    }
}, 5000);
```

but it didn't work.

What I am trying to achieve is having a page auto-refresh after a certain interval but ONLY when the user is in the state associated to that page.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain about what do you mean about state change..?

Comment: Think he's using ui-router. Try $timeout instead of $interval.

Comment: yes, I am using ui-router, I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to destroy method of scope, and cancel interval there.

```
    var stop = $interval(function() {
        console.log("Refreshed!");
        findData();

    }, 5000);

scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $interval.cancel(stop);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're getting at correctly, better to handle this with an event listener for state changes:

```
$scope.on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(e, toState) {
    if(toState.name === 'stateWithRefresh') {
        findData();
    }
});
```